# Прижать футер к нижней части экрана в Polymer

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, polymer

Подскажите, как прижать `footer` к нижней части экрана в Polymer? Чтобы при небольшом количестве контента «подвал» всегда оставался внизу. В Polymer'е всё построено flex-блоками, но выравнивание футера к низу что-то не поддаётся.

Может быть уже есть какой-нибудь готовый веб-компонент?

Код:

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <paper-drawer-panel>
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar fixed></paper-toolbar>
     </paper-header-panel>
     <paper-header-panel main>
       <paper-toolbar fixed></paper-toolbar>
       <main>
         <section class="main-section">
           <paper-material>
             <p>Content</p>
           </paper-material>
         </section>
       </main>
       <footer>
         <p>Footer</p>
       </footer>
     </paper-header-panel>
   </paper-drawer-panel>
 </body>
```

Как это выглядит:

[image: Как это выглядит]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать CSS-функцию `calc` и рассчитать минимальную высоту блока `main`:

```
<style>
  main {
    min-height: calc(100% - Xpx);
  }
  footer {
    background: green;
    height: Xpx;
  }
</style>
```

В общем случае `X` если у вас нет других элементов, в случае с заголовком надо будет учесть и его.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще один пример

```
<footer style="position:fixed;bottom:0">
    Sticky footer?
  </footer>
```

или

```
<div class="fit vertical layout">
  <paper-header-panel class="flex">
  ...
  </paper-header-panel>

  <footer>
    Sticky footer?
  </footer>
</div>
```

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162019/how-to-add-sticky-footer-to-polymer-starter-kit-with-iron-pages)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```css
html, body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

footer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Если нужен внутренний отступ для `footer`, оберните его содержимое в `div` и задайте для него отступ.